# what is requirements of first application using the TEE?

Tags: android, arm

I want to write first app using TEE ( Trusted Execution environment ) in Android. I do not know what is requirements of starting this work.

I just survey that there are some API in GlobalPatform standard for TA and CA applications.

I am primary in C and java programming and I do not have any experience in ARM Programming.

Answer (score 3):

You need lots of things. You can start by choosing a trusted execution environment that might be open-source like [Open-TEE](https://github.com/Open-TEE), this one follows the GlobalPlatform standard, i also suggest you try to install and develop your work in linux. Regarding the CA/TA, it will be in C and after you build them correctly you will need to integrate them with Java code (your Android application), use JNI functions for that.